# Is There a TSpinEdit for Floats in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, controls

Is there really not a TSpinEdit control for floats in Delphi?  It looks like there are [third party components](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advspin.asp) that supply a control that will work.

How do you implement TSpinEdit for floats?  I've been creating my own with a TEDit field and a TSpinButton positioned right beside it but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Yes. There is. Here is one.  Commercial ($10) - http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-Delphi_float_spin_edit/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TJvSpinEdit is a part of the [JEDI Visual Component Library](http://homepages.codegear.com/jedi/jvcl/).
As far as I know it has a property called ValueType which you can set to vtFloat.

Comment: It works just fine as a float spinner. You just set ValueType tp vtFloat and Increment to some floating number and off you go.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Are there some screenshots of all the controls that are available with that library?  Tks.

Comment: There are about 500 visual components in the JVCL... so, no Screenshot, but you can download the "MegaDemo" here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there exists no such component in Delphi.

I'm also using a component from a 3rd party library, [SpTBXLib](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/index.htm), which is very good for other things, too.

Comment: actually there are. example: http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-Delphi_float_spin_edit/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Even if there aren't, you can easily create one using two buttons and a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is non in Delphi, but you can create your own.
I have done so for my open source project, you might [check it](https://monex.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/monex/trunk/Komponente/SteviloEdit/) out as a starting point for your own.

**EDIT**: You will also need following two file to get it working:

- [KomponenteSplosno.pas](https://monex.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/monex/trunk/Komponente/Splosno/KomponenteSplosno.pas)
- [RisanjeSplosno.pas](https://monex.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/monex/trunk/Knjiznice/RisanjeSplosno.pas)

Comment: links are not there anymore

Comment: Seems that SourceForge has moved files around. Try your luck at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/monex/ don't know the state the project is in haven't touched it for some years.